# URL Issue in Silver Light. Donot show .xaml path

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silver light application. When I run it then its URL is like

```
http://localhost/Myfirstapplication.aspx
```

I have created another silver light application. Mostly code is copied from first application. But when I run it then its URL is like

```
http://localhost/mysecondapplication.aspx#loginpage.xaml.
```

Actually I donot want to show .xaml path/name. Can any body tell me what setting should I made to hide .XAML or am I missing somthing ???

Answer (score 0):

URI Routing is what you need. Please see [this link](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/03/22/silverlight-navigation-framework-and-uri-routing.aspx), going to help you to find the way.